# NullPointerException con un array de Listas de Nodos

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un array con listas de nodos que tengo que organizarlas de otra Lista que contiene 200 Nodos con un valor del 0 al 9 cada uno (valor asignado random). 
Los Nodos deben de eliminarse de la Lista principal y asignarse a la Lista correspondiente dentro del array según su valor. 
Por ejemplo, si al eliminar un Nodo que tiene un 8 dentro, debo de asignarlo a la Lista en la posición 8 dentro del array. Ese while es para borrar y asignar los Nodos pero me arroja NullPointerException al momento de llamar al metodo addEnd.

Este es el código donde me sale el error:

```
while(n > 0){
    Nodo x = myList.deletStart();
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        if(a == x.getInfo()){
            arr[a].addEnd(x);
            //arr[a].addEnd(new Nodo(x.getInfo()));
            break;
        }
    }
    myList.mostrar();
    System.out.println();
    n--;
}
```

Inicializo la Lista de esta forma:

```
static Lista[] arr = new Lista[10];
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow! ¿Puedes poner [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Como está es muy difícil averiguar qué está mal. A otras personas en situación similar ha sido posible ayudarlas cuando han editado su pregunta para que el error sea reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Este error se debe a uno de estos factores (o varios), seguro que si lo revisas ya verás el error:

- Acceder a una posición `null` o inexistente.
- Alterar o visualizar atributos de objetos en `null`
- No controlar el tamaño de un `array`.

En tu caso no puedes eliminar primero y luego asignar, ya que simplemente no existe.

```
while(n > 0){
    Nodo x = myList.deletStart();
    for(int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        if(a == x.getInfo()){
            arr[a].addEnd(x);
            //arr[a].addEnd(new Nodo(x.getInfo()));
            break;
        }
    }
    myList.mostrar();
    System.out.println();
    n--;
}
```

Tienes que usar una tercera variable ej. **aux** que contenga el elemento si quieres borrarlo desde el principio.

Answer (score 0):

```
static Lista[] arr = new Lista[10];
```

'arr' ya lo inicializaste y se creó un array de tipo 'Lista' pero con todas sus posiciones vacías (nulas). Entonces cuando haces esto: 
    arr[a].addEnd(x);
intentas utilizar el método 'addEnd(x)' de un objeto nulo.

Lo que debes hacer es validar:

```
if(arr[a] == null) {
    arr[a] = new Lista();
}
else {
    arr[a].addEnd(x);
}
```

Mira este ejemplo en el debug del Eclipse donde todos los elementos del array 'o' no están inicializados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]